# Writing text letter by letter

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze

I'm somewhat new to programming and Python. I'm actually making a little function which write a sentence letter by letter. Here's the code :

```
import time

def slowWriting(txt, speed=0.01):
    for c in txt:
        print(c, end='\r')
        time.sleep(speed)
    print()
```

The issue is that when building the function with cxfreeze, and executing the .exe, for the line :

```
<module_name>.slowWriting("abcd")
```

Instead of displaying :

```
abcd
```

The console displays :

```
d
```

In fact, when a character is displayed, he replaces the previous displayed character...
How to make it work ?

Thanks for reading and your potential answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\r` is carriage return. It returns the cursor to the beginning of the line. That is why you are seeing this behavior. You should use `''` as the end character for `print`.

Comment: Just adding that the default end character for print is `\n` To start a new line. So depends on what do you want you don't need to specify it.